# How to extract RegEx from http response?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am using Jmeter 2.11 and My http response after login as follows,

```
"apiResponseStatus": "SUCCESS",
"authToken": "o5SsJF9yOebRC9LsR5WCnYUNpslddO30Db/zBAdhBW/ISfL62CaOHqmSkrAHZ8RT4XF6yaGxX6kbmpACZu212Q=="
```

How to write RegEx for this to reuse same token throughout the Test Plan?

Comment: Don't use regex for extracting things from HTTP responses. There are hundreds of parsers.

Comment: Looks like your response is in fact in JSON, you should parse it as json.

Comment: Using JSON path extractor I am getting this error Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/Filter

Comment: **@Maroun Maroun** can you please tel which parser should I use for this response?

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression Extractor with below details:

***Apply to*** --> *Main Sample Only*
***Response Field to check*** --> *Body*

**Reference Name:** *auth_token*
**Regular Expression:** *.authToken": "(.+?)".*
**Template:** *$1$*
**Match No.:** *1*
**Default Value:** *Not Found*

You can pass **Reference Name** as ${auth_token} where it is required throughout your test plan.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have tried the Regex using Jmeter before sharing it with you. I believe you are using it in the same way including spaces. This will work if you receive the above shared response in the web page and not in the header or Cookie. There is a different way of capturing values from cookie or header.